# how to show the new data after sent requests and states changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a service with the following:

```
.service('TasksService', function ($http) {
      return $http.jsonp('http://blabla/json/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
 });
```

My controller:

```
.controller("TasksCtrl", function ($scope, TasksService) {
            TasksService.then(function (TasksService) {
                $scope.Tasks = TasksService;
            });
        });
```

This shows list with many items.
But I have another service and another controller. I change an item there and when I save and post data to database and I get back to initial list, I still see the old listed items. I must refresh the browser to see what I have edited.

In the second controller I have save function with this:

```
$scope.saveTask = function () {
    $http.post('http://blabla', $scope.Task.data).then(function (data) {
        // This shows the very first state with all the listed items
        $state.go('tasks'); 
    });
  };
```

When I save the changes and `state.go()` shows me the first screen I do not know why the data is not with the new changes from the service returned data. It seems like the screen is just changed but the new data is not returned from the service. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How do yo **get back** to initial list? Is the `TasksCtrl` reloaded ?

Comment: Just with $state.go('tasks'), the TasksCtrl should be reloaded, because its related with the ui-router.. but not 100% sure

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. I changed my service and controller. In my service I returned an object with another method and then I changed my controller also to use the returned method.

The service:

```
.service('TasksService', function ($http) {
            return {
                getTasks: function() {
                    return $http.jsonp('http://blabla/json/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
                }
            };
        });
```

And the controller:

```
.controller("TasksCtrl", function ($scope, TasksService) {
            TasksService.getTasks().then(function (data) {
                $scope.Tasks = data;
            });
        });
```

Now it is working and I see the items list the new saved and returned data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to reflect the changed data into your html
Angular has a method for this

```
$scope.$apply();
```

This method works both with parameters as well as without parameters.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot handle where to put it. Its telling me all the time that $digest is already in progress

Comment: This is to be used instead of $state.go()
Alternatively you can reload your state, so that new changes may be applied to your scope